# unable to run batch file in docker windows container

Tags: docker, containers, jbossfuse, docker-for-windows

I am trying to run Jboss fuse in a windows container. I have all required binaries in a folder and able to copy them to container, but when i run the batch file to start the service in the container nothing happens. The same batch file works fine in my local. What am i missing ?

Running binary from my local works like this

```
PS C:\serverbox\jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187\bin> .\JbossFuse-Karaf-service.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | Please wait while JBoss Fuse is loading...
jvm 1    | Feb 01, 2018 3:33:51 PM org.apache.karaf.main.SimpleFileLock lock
jvm 1    | INFO: locking
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    |   1% [>                                                                       ]
jvm 1    |   2% [=>                                                                      ]
jvm 1    |   3% [==>                                                                     ]
```

when i copy the same binary to container and run the same batch file it looks like this..

```
PS C:\serverbox\jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187\bin> .\JbossFuse-Karaf-service.bat
PS C:\serverbox\jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187\bin>
```

it doesn't do anything.

I am new to docker and not sure how volumes work in a container. When the path says c:\serverbox, does container understand that and go to that folder with in container ?

Comment: You are missing a [mcve].

Comment: Check your dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, containers dont work with relative windows path's like this C:\serverbox\jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187\bin..\etc

Path need to be absolute C:\serverbox\jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187\etc.

Hope this helps.